# search pc on a network by serial number/service tag

Tags: script

I need a software or script or some way to find a PC in a domain. The problem is that I know only the serial number / service tag, so I need to scan all pc's and filter by SN

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: at work i'm using Advanced IP Scanner, but it doesn't display the serial number of the pc's

Comment: All enterprise PC makers have software that can do this

Comment: does the serial number look anything like a MAC address?

Comment: @Jasen no, it is a serice tag

Comment: the title says "or"

Comment: the service tag or serial number are the same thing